# Mocking Private Objects in Ballerina Classes for Unit Testing

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I'm currently writing unit tests for the functions inside the "ConsentManagementServiceImpl" class.However, the initiation of this class involves creating a DAO layer object. I want to mock the private final object (consentManagementDAO) and mock its methods whenever they are called. How can I do that?

Here is my code

```
public isolated client class ConsentManagementImpl {
    private final dao:ConsentManagementDAO consentManagementDAO;

    public isolated function init(string host, string username, string password, string database, int port) returns error? {
        self.consentManagementDAO = check new(host, username, password, database, port);
       }

    public isolated function handle consentAmendment(string consenId, string payload, string orgId) returns error?
        check self.consentManagementDAO->updateConsent(consentId, orgId, payload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `consentManagementDAO` is within the scope of the client class `ConsentManagementServiceImpl`, we cannot mock it as it is. With the current implementation, we can only mock the `ConsentManagementServiceImpl` using object mocking. But, that way we can't test the implementation within that class.
To achieve the requirement, we can move the `consentManagementDAO` out of the class(as a module level final client) and then use the approach mentioned in https://ballerina.io/learn/test-ballerina-code/test-services-and-clients/#mock-final-clients to mock this final client.